# What is Default Font in Progress 4GL?

Tags: fonts, progress-4gl

I have a problem: what font of the second string is on the picture below? I know, that it is default font for Progress 4GL, but i don't know it's name. Please, help somebody..[image]

Comment: I'm not sure why this was downvoted. Perhaps editing the question would make it clearer that the asker doesn't know where to look; regardless, please leave a comment for the sake of improvement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look in %DLC%\bin\progress.ini

```
[Startup]
V6Display=no
;ImmediateDisplay=yes
;MultitaskingInterval=100
DefaultFont=MS Sans Serif, size=8
...
```